# Using sed to fix pdf files

Tags: pdf, sed, malformed, nul

I am running GNU sed version 4.2.1 on windows. I have a huge number of PDF files having `%%EOF` + newline + a lot of NUL chars in the last record.

See hexdump below.

```
0000b890: 25 25 45 4F 46 0D 0A 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |%%EOF           
|

0000b8a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |                
|
```

I need to change the last record to be `%%EOF` only. The expression `^%%EOF\x0d\x0a\x0{10,30000}` matches the characters in Notepad++, but it seems it does not work in sed. Is anyone able to help? Many thanks.

Comment: sed operates line oriented so you can't match multi line strings that easily. Your pattern contains \x0a i.e. newline characters. I think sed is not the best choice for that task but might be possible if used expert-level. What's the problem with the newline and null bytes following the %%EOF?

Comment: Those files cannot be open by Adobe Reader XI.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your grep supports it, for a given *input.pdf* do

Read the byte offset of the last %%EOF in the file into the variable offset

```
offset=$( grep -a -b '%%EOF' input.pdf  | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1 )
```

cut off the first *offset + 5* bytes (the length of the string `%%EOF`) from the original file, then the *output.pdf* should be what you wanted

```
head -c$(( $offset + 5 )) input.pdf > output.pdf
```

But depending on the nature of the PDF (e.g. no %%EOF at all at the end, (**edit:**  or other data but null bytes following the `%%EOF`[thx @mkl) this might behave different from what you want or cause a lot of other problems.

Comment: *"cut off the first offset + 5 bytes (the length of the string %%EOF) from the original file"* - but that's not what the op wants,  he wants to delete a tail of 0 bytes following the '%%EOF`- line.

Comment: I admit this is independent of if there are null bytes or other data behind the %%EOF, you are right